# UML Class Diagram: default values of the method parameters

Tags: uml, class-diagram

According to UML (or its standard use), can I use default values for the class method parameters, although these default values are the invocation to some subroutine?. I am especially interested when the subroutine belongs to a third party library. For example: I am using OpenCV in my application, can I / should I indicate the routine cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3,3)) as the default value of a parameter of a method in my class diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Like in your other question it depends on the readership or the intention of the current diagram. The model itself will have the default parameter, but you can/will show/suppress it in diagrams intentionally. An overview diagram will show only the class name. Finer detailed diagrams include attributes/operations and detail diagrams will also show defaults and signature detail.